# Fundamental vectors fields (Example)

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, vector-fields

> Definition: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold on which acts a lie group $G$. Let $X$ be an element in the lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$, we associate to it the vector field $X_M$ called the fundamental vector field defined by $$X_M(m)= \frac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=0} e^{-tX}.m.$$

Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of $H$. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold on which $H$ acts on the left.

Let's consider the  action of  $H$ on $G \times M$ : $$h((g,m)):= (gh,h^{-1}m), \quad h \in H , g \in G , m \in M, $$ and define the manifold $Z$ to be  the quotient $G  \times_H M .$

The group $G$ acts on $Z:= G \times _H M$ by $g'.[g,m]:= [g'g,m].$

Let $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, What is $X_Z$ ? i.e if $[g,m] \in G \times_H M$, then how can we continue this calculation:

$$X_Z([g,m])= \frac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=0} e^{-tX}.[g,m]= \frac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=0} [e^{-tX}g,m] ?$$

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: In simpler  cases where for example $M$ is a vector space, or $H= \lbrace e \rbrace$, what is $X_Z$ ? Please give me any  hints or comments about this (I don't have enough of baground in differential geometry , and I'm not able to advance in any further step in this question).

Comment: I don't think you can go any further calculation, since the tangent bundle of $G\times _H M$ is rather complicated. But if we take some petty special case, as you'd mentioned in the comment, we can take $H$ the trivial subgroup, $M$ be the dual Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}^*$, then the quotient Space is exactly the cotangent bundle $T^*G=G\times \mathfrak{g}^*$ (since the (co)tangent bundle over any Lie group is trivial), and the action you defined above is just the left action on the cotangent bundle, I know this fundamental vector field is $\underline{X}(g,A)=\mathrm{Ad}_{g^{-1}}A$.